# What do I put in the drupal 7 commerce Checkout Completed Rules: Send Email field to display all of the order data?

Tags: 7, rules, commerce

Currently I have the following below in my completed checkout send email settings. But when i receive the emails on a completed order, I'm still missing some data even though I have it set there. Would someone please paste their completed order send email setup?

See below as it only shows the SKU reference #'s.

One main issue I'm having is for these tokens:

[commerce-order:commerce-line-items] -- Only gives the Product ID number and nothing else

[commerce-order:commerce_line_items] -- Displays "No line items found".

[image]

[image: does not show item names]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a permissions issue related to line items and anonymous users. See https://drupal.org/node/1811972, and https://drupal.org/node/1333174.

This does not answer your exact question, but what I've done recently is install Commerce Invoice Receipt (https://drupal.org/project/commerce_invoice_receipt) as a solution. Here's the basic checklist I followed:

1. install commerce invoice receipt (dev version has support for logo)
2. set visibility of fields at admin/commerce/config/order/display/invoice
3. disable SQL query rewriting on on Line items view - needed for line
   items to appear when emailed to customer (security issue, but I'm not sure how serious)
4. create a new rule with Send Invoice Receipt action - for customers
5. create a new rule with Send Invoice Receipt action - for admins
6. disable rule: Send an order notification e-mail

Comment: great thanks.. didnt know there was a module for that. i don't really want to install all this bloatware and just stick to the core commerce module if possible, but it seems like sacrifices will have to be made.

Comment: Yes, I completely understand. It seems like such a simple thing.